# How to rename volumes from Terminal without name limitations?

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, disk-volume

When a FAT volume is mounted I can click on it and rename it freely.

However via terminal it is very restrictive.

```
% /usr/sbin/diskutil rename "Nice Name" "Nicer Name" 
Nicer Name does not appear to be a valid volume name for its file system
```

Is there an other way, or a list of limitations?

Comment: Can you also update the question to show the real volume names you are using?

Comment: Those are the name I was using. I renamed NO NAME to Nice Name using the GUI and then failed renaming it to "Nicer Name" using the terminal.

Comment: have you tried to rename with full CAPS to see how it goes?

Answer (score 1):

The FAT volume name mustn't contain:

```
* ? / \ | . , ; : + = [ ] < > "
```

You are limited to 11 characters. Using `diskutil rename ...` no umlauts etc. & all upper case.

Comment: It's a two parter, is there an alternative renaming the volumes programmatically?

Comment: @OrigamiEye Sure: mlable with the same restrictions